# 90 degree text rotation in a table

Tags: html, css, rotation

I am trying to align text in the top row of a table so that it displays vertically using the rotate transform function.  Although i successfully rotate the word in the table header, i am unable to shorten the width of the table column to be the same width of the rotated title.  (It stays the same width of the title if it were to have been layed out horizontally).  Also, I am using percentages to indicate column width.

```css
.vertical-th {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="3" class="text-center risk-th" style="width: 20%">Controls</th>
    <th class="risk-th" style="width: 4%">
      <!--Manuality-->
    </th>
    <th class="risk-th" style="width: 4%">
      <!--Probability-->
    </th>
    <th class="risk-th" style="width: 4%">
      <!--Gravity-->
    </th>
    <th class="risk-th" style="width: 4%">
      <!--Mitigation-->
    </th>

    <th colspan="3"></th>
    <th class="vertical-th">Manuality</th>
    <th class="vertical-th">Probability</th>
    <th class="vertical-th">Gravity</th>
    <th class="vertical-th">Mitigation</th>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you create a working jsFiddle demo with maybe a screenshot of desired result? It's not clear for me: https://jsfiddle.net/Lxw0x2db/

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this.  I am just hoping that the words; Manuality, Probability, Gravity, and Mitigation are ligned up side by side but rotated 90 degrees reading from the (bottom to the top of the page)..  (e.g. the M from Manualityh will be next to the P from probability, etc.)

Comment: Can you explain why the need for table? Is it possible to alter the HTML structure?

Comment: Underneath each heading there will be data coming from an sql query. From what i understand, to ensure the that the interface is responsive to multiple screen sizes, the best way to do this is with a table otherwise the column heading get misaligned. (ps- i am new to this type of programming as you can see)

Comment: OK. Can you please create sample data and make a screenshot of how it should look?

Comment: @MarcheseIlChihuahua Please review my answer if it was helpful to you, if not, we will find another solutions if you want, Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do some CSS tricks by warping headers text inside `DIV's` and applying some rules on `th` and the `DIV's` inside it, then we can get more styling ability then we can shorten the width of header even if text is long.

***Some thing like:*** *I hope it helps for you, Thanks*

```css
th, td, table{
  border:solid 1px;
}

div.vertical{
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Safari/Chrome */
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);    /* Firefox */
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);      /* Opera */
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);     /* IE 9 */
}

th.vertical{
  max-width: 50px;
  height: 85px;
  line-height: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: inherit;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="3" class="text-center risk-th" style="width: 20%">Controls</th>
    <th class="risk-th" style="width: 4%">
      <!--Manuality-->
    </th>
    <th class="risk-th" style="width: 4%">
      <!--Probability-->
    </th>
    <th class="risk-th" style="width: 4%">
      <!--Gravity-->
    </th>
    <th class="risk-th" style="width: 4%">
      <!--Mitigation-->
    </th>

    <th class="vertical"><div class="vertical">Manuality</div></th>
    <th class="vertical"><div class="vertical">Probability</div></th>
    <th class="vertical"><div class="vertical">Gravity</div></th>
    <th class="vertical"><div class="vertical">Mitigation</div></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5):

Simple and easy way to create rotational table header by using below concept.

```js
$(function() {
    var header_height = 0;
    $('.rotate-table-grid th span').each(function() {
        if ($(this).outerWidth() > header_height) header_height = $(this).outerWidth();
    });

    $('.rotate-table-grid th').height(header_height);
});
```

```css
table.rotate-table-grid{box-sizing: border-box;
border-collapse: collapse;}
 .rotate-table-grid tr, .rotate-table-grid td, .rotate-table-grid th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}
.rotate-table-grid th span {
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  transform: rotate(-90deg); 
  white-space: nowrap; 
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="rotate-table-grid">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th><span>Shorter Title</span></th>
          <th><span>Much Much Longer Title</span></th>
           <th><span>Shorter Title</span></th>
          <th><span>Much Much Longer Title</span></th>
           <th><span>Shorter Title</span></th>
          <th><span>Much Much Longer Title</span></th>
           <th><span>Shorter Title</span></th>
          <th><span>Much Much Longer Title</span></th>
      </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
         <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Omg, been trying this in combination width bootstrap for 2 days. This is the best answer when using bootstrap and nowrap of cells.

Comment: Thanks @Gulpener for your feedback... and i hope you will promote this solution among people -:)

Answer (score 1):

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
     <th style="transform: rotate(-90deg);width: 1px;padding: 10px;" className="rotateth">head 1</th>
     <th>head 2</th>
     <th>head 3</th>
     <th>head 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>data 1</td>
     <td>data 2</td>
     <td>data 3</td>
     <td>data 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: When answering an old question, your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users if you included some context to explain how your answer helps, particularly for a question that already has an accepted answer. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).