# Rotate text in markdown

Tags: markdown

I want to rotate the letter C in markdown by 180° in accordance to Peano's notation of the material implication. I would also like to rotate some text by 90° in a table. Would someone know how to do it? Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Markdown doesn't do anything like that. [It is a very simple format](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html):

> Markdown is not a replacement for HTML, or even close to it. Its syntax is very small, corresponding only to a very small subset of HTML tags. The idea is *not* to create a syntax that makes it easier to insert HTML tags. In my opinion, HTML tags are already easy to insert. The idea for Markdown is to make it easy to read, write, and edit prose. HTML is a *publishing* format; Markdown is a *writing* format. Thus, Markdown’s formatting syntax only addresses issues that can be conveyed in plain text.

The CommonMark standard [also does not support tables](https://spec.commonmark.org/current/), though some tools and implementations include extensions for such things.

It sounds like you are writing scientific or mathematical content. You might want to choose a tool that supports embedded [TeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX). Several Markdown implementations do this, but again, Markdown itself does not.

Alternatively, you might find an appropriate Unicode character, e.g. `Ɔ` ([LATIN CAPITAL LETTER OPEN O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_O)).

For rotating text in a table I suspect you'll need to use [inline HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36814921/354577).